# Time expressions in PHP

Tags: php

I am developing a website for a golf club. They allow their members to book for a game from 6:00 PM 14 days before the date of the game. In developing their booking calendar I already have code to check for the 14 days.

A simple helper function:

> function day_in_month( $d, $m, $y )
> {
> return mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m, $d, $y );

A variable:

> $cutoff_date = strtotime( 'today + 14 days' );

And the calculation which only shows allowed booking days on the calendar:

> day_in_month( $onday, $month, $year) > $cutoff_date

What I would like to know is: how can I allow for the 6:00 PM on the 14th day before? I'm sure there is a simple answer, but at the end of a long day I thought I'd ask my fellow programmers rather than going through my code books or Googling.

Comment: You probably want `strtotime( 'today 18:00:00 + 14 days')`

Comment: Not a direct answer to your questions, but I suggest you look at the [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) library for PHP. It makes time calculations and presentations so much easier.

Comment: I know I was being lazy, so I probably deserve the knock down from 0 to -2. (You wouldn't think that I had been contributing to StackOverflow for years.) Thank you to user3783243, for an obvious suggestion which I will try.

Comment: Unfortunately, the formula as suggested by @user3783243 doesn't work. What I have done is transfer the time condition to the booking page:
`$booking_opens = strtotime( '-14 days 18:00:00', $edate );`
But on the calendar page this doesn't work:
`$today = time();
    $cutoff_date = strtotime( '+14 days 18:00:00', $today );`
I would be delighted to know why the first expression works, and the second doesn't!

Answer (score -2):

For Example, if the Game date is: '22-2-2022 18:00:00'

You have to convert your game date time to timestamp, so in the first line changed to timestamp, as I understood based on your question, you would like to do some things 14 days before determined game start. consequentially, you have to find start date by eliminating 14 days( each day has:24 hours, each hour has:60 minutes, each minute has: 60 seconds), then finally you achieve start timestamp.
Overall, day, month and year of start date calculated by date() function, but if you like to triggered an event, timestamp comprehension is the best choice.

```
$game_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', '22-2-2022 18:00:00');
$game_date_timestamp = strtotime($game_date);
$start_date=$game_date_timestamp -(14*24*60*60);
echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s', $start_date);
```

Comment: You've muddled two styles of date handing here: your first line gives you a DateTine object, but your next two assume it's an integer timestamp, as would be given by strtotime

Comment: Also not all days have 24 hours. Some have 23, and others have 25.

Comment: @IMSoP you're right, I  forgot to mention strtotime()  function to obtained timestamp from object, and, dear Sammitch, are you sure?

Comment: Just to support @Sammitch: in every country which has daylight saving, at least one day has 23 hours, and at least one day has 25 hours.